# No Data Saved when i create new user

Tags: php, yii2

am trying to create new user

i modified this code

```
 public function actionCreate() {
   $model = new Users;

   if(isset($_POST['Users'])) {
      if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
         if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['']);
         }
      }

   } else {
      return $this->render('create', [
           'model' => $model,
      ]);
   }

}
```

but it's not saving !! 
how can find the problem ??

Comment: debug your code, and show method $model->load()

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

`$model = new Users;
if(isset($_POST['Users'])) {
      $model->attributes = $_POST['Users']; //instead of if($model->load(...
      if($model->save()){
          return $this->redirect(['']);
      }
.....
....`

The `$model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];` will get the posted values and set the `$model` object perfectly unless your `$model->load( [.....] )` is called for some extra code.

So as asked by @Alex, you need to mention what exactly `$model->load()` does.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model = new users;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
  }
```

hope it works!